# Adobe Illustrator - Transparency Issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm a professional Adobe Illustrator user with over 8 years experience but this issue is leaving me stumped.  I've created some artwork for the front of a booklet - it uses 3 jpeg textures set to the Luminosity transparency mode, each contained within a clipping mask around the central cube logo.  You can see on the screenshot below how it should look. However no matter what I export to, it ends up looking like the jpg! The transparency mode has been completely ignored. Any ideas? I've never had this before.

Screenshot from Illustrator:
http://www.obelysk.co.uk/ftp/issue-screenshot.png

Exported Jpeg:
http://www.obelysk.co.uk/ftp/issue-result.jpg

Comment: how is this issue programming related?

Comment: My apologies - I was directed to this site by a colleague, they informed me it was for help on all kinds of issues - thanks for informing me, I'll take my question elsewhere!

Comment: Try this stack [graphicdesign-illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I spent hours messing around, and finally simply copy and pasting everything into a new Illustrator document did the trick. I would also recommend potentially reinstalling Illustrator if that doesn't work.